# Adding a function to java program

Tags: java, function, uppercase

I am writing my very first java program, I finally got it all written but on the assignment I need to add a function (other than main). My program counts the number of letter in first name, so I was thinking maybe I could add a function that reads how many letters are uppercase? Any ideas?

```
public class NameLetters{

    public static void main(String []args){  

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String firstName;   //Asks for the users first name

        int count=0;        //Count the letters passing through loop

        System.out.print("Hello, this program will ask for your first name and then output the number of letters in your name.");

        System.out.print("Please enter your first name:");

        String firstName = input.NextLine();

        for (int i=0; i<firstName.length(); i++) {
            if (firstName.charAt(i) != ' ')
                Count ++;
        } 

        system.out.print("There are "+Count+" s in the first name "+firstName+" , Thank you for participating. Goodbye!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, read a tutorial, e.g. http://www.learnjavaonline.org/en/Functions

Comment: Use [`Character.isUpperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-).

Answer (score -1):

```
            String s = "NaMe";
            int upper = 0;
            int lower = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i<s.length();i++ ) {
                int charASCII= (int)s.charAt(i);
                if (charASCII <91 && charASCII > 64){
                    upper ++;
                }
                if (charASCII <123 && charASCII > 96){
                    lower ++;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Given name string contains "+upper+ " uppercase letters & "+lower + " lowercase letters");
```

Comment: this is no separate function, and it only works with US-ascii strings